# Shopware 6 installation assisstent Not Found after downloading

Tags: shopware, shopware6

Want to test SW6.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vm02L.png)

After executing the phap.php file and downloading Shopware6 the installation "asssistent" is supposed to start where you can choose the database etc. However error "Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server." appears after the download is complete. The SW6 files are downloaded fully as far as i can tell.

Server was freshly set up. System requirements are met.

Following the installation guide from Shopware 6 community edition. After downloading the setup/installer is supposed to load automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Can you point me to the exact version you tried to download so I can reproduce the issue? Where did you download it from?
Another really good possibility would be to use dockware.io (play) for your tests ;)

Comment: Version is 6.5.8.4. Downloaded from the official Shopware 6 website. https://www.shopware.com/en/download/?_gl=1%2a1lrwuwn%2a_ga%2aodi4nji4otcylje3mdywmtq0otq.%2a_ga_9jlj6ggb76%2amtcwnzcyota3ms44ljaumtcwnzcyota3nc4wljauma..

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the issue you're encountering stems from the server's document root configuration. In Shopware 6, the public folder should be set as the document root of your web server. This is a common setup detail that can lead to the "Not Found" error you're experiencing if not configured correctly.

To resolve this, ensure that your web server (Apache, Nginx, etc.) is configured to serve files from the public directory of your Shopware 6 installation. This configuration step is crucial for the installation assistant to load properly and for the application to function as intended.

However, if you're looking for a smoother Shopware development experience, you might want to consider using a development environment specifically tailored for Shopware, such as Dockware or DDEV. These tools can significantly simplify the setup process and offer a more streamlined development workflow.

**Dockware**: https://dockware.io - Dockware provides a Docker environment tailored for Shopware, making it easy to spin up a Shopware instance with various configurations and versions, including pre-configured development, testing, and production environments.

**DDEV**: https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/stable/users/quickstart/#shopware - DDEV is a versatile Docker-based development environment that supports Shopware among other platforms. It offers an easy-to-use workflow for local development, with comprehensive documentation to get you started quickly.

Using Dockware or DDEV can help you avoid common setup pitfalls and focus on developing your Shopware project.

Comment: But you can only change the root to public after it is downloaded. The installer downloads the files and then immediately tries to execute the setup assisstant from the /public/installer directory. Can you test a migration from SW5 to SW6 with Dockware? Thats what we are currently trying to test.